# Error JSON.parse, how to convert an array jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a AJAX call that  returns some JSON like this one:

```
   while($row= $stmt->fetch()){

                echo json_encode(array('model' =>$model ));



        }
```

the **output** is this

```
{"model":"MDX"}{"model":"NSX"}{"model":"RL"}{"model":"TL"}{"model":"TSX"}{"model":"RDX"}{"model":"CSX"}{"model":"ZDX"}{"model":"ILX"}{"model":"RLX"}{"model":"TLX"}
```

how can i get just the values of that array?

the thing is that i need to convert that array to plain text like..

```
MDX
NSX
RLd
TL
TSX
RDX
etc..
```

when i recive the callback  tried this but is throwing me out  an error

```
$.ajax({

       type:"POST",
       url:url,
       data:{category_brand:category_brand},
       datatype:"json",
       contenType: "application/json",
   }).done(function(response){

           var text=response;
           var obj=JSON.parse(text);

           console.log(obj);


   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

     console.log(textStatus);

   })
```

this is tje error

### 1. > **Uncaught SyntaxError:** Unexpected token { in JSON at position 15 at JSON.parse () at Object. (main.js:8838) at i (jquery.min.js:2) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2) at y (jquery.min.js:4) at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)

can someone help me please, im no that good in **json**

Comment: *"how can i get just the values of that array?"* That's not a JSON array.

Comment: oh sorry and what is it ? im a little bit of new

Comment: It's just a list of JSON objects. In your PHP, you need to add all your values to an array, and then `json_encode()` that array.

Answer (score 1):

Paste your json in a validation tool such as the one here: https://jsonlint.com/ and see what happens. You will get the same error (but in different words).

To put your json in an array, it would look like this:

```
[{"model":"MDX"},{"model":"NSX"},{"model":"RL"},{"model":"TL"},{"model":"TSX"},{"model":"RDX"},{"model":"CSX"},{"model":"ZDX"},{"model":"ILX"},{"model":"RLX"},{"model":"TLX"}]
```

The key bit being the `[` and `,` and `]`.

What is happening is you have multiple roots, but JSON supports only a single root element. It is reading `{"model":"MDX"}` and as it hits the last `}` it is seeing the end of the root element (ie the end of the json document). It throws the error because it sees something else there that shouldn't be.

Comment: i see now that  tool is so helpfull! but how can i get an array just like the one you posted :(

Comment: You are json encoding each tiny piece, which ruins the whole lot. Example: you encode this: `echo json_encode(array('model' =>$model ));` which equals this `{"model":"MDX"}` then you add that to your output with echo. This will output each little piece in valid json but when added together its not valid.

Comment: What you could do is (and excuse the pseudo code; I don't know php):

`while($row= $stmt->fetch()){
                $array.push(array('model' =>$model ));
}
echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: i did it like this way `$data=array();  while($row= $stmt->fetch()){  array('model'=>$data[]=$model );  }  echo json_encode($data);` and the ouput iia this `["MDX","NSX","RL","TL","TSX","RDX","CSX","ZDX","ILX","RLX","TLX"]`

Comment: That way is just putting `$model` into the `$data[]`. If you wanted the 'model' part in the json, then you could do: `$data=array(); while($row= $stmt->fetch()){ $data[] = array('model'=>$model ); } echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

i solved it! this way

```
 $data=array();

    while($row= $stmt->fetch()){

        array('model' =>$data[]=$model );

        }
       echo json_encode($data);
```

and the **js file**

```
$.ajax({

       type:"POST",
       url:url,
       data:{category_brand:category_brand},
       datatype:"json",
       contenType: "application/json",
   }).done(function(response){          

                var text=response;
               var obj=JSON.parse(text);

               console.log(obj);


obj.forEach( function(value, index, array) {
    console.log("in the index " + index + " there is this value: " + value);

});
```